# Memory leak when creating array from parts of string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

timeListArray is my global variable in class
Here is my Code:-

```
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *return_string5 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *dairyTimeParts = [return_string5 componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""];
[timeListArray removeAllObjects];

for(int i=1;i<[dairyTimeParts count]/2;i=i+2)
{
    [timeListArray addObject:[dairyTimeParts objectAtIndex:2*i+1]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line:

```
NSString *return_string5 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

In a nutshell, anything you `alloc` yourself you must `release` when you are done with it.  Try adding a `[return_string5 release];` after your `for` loop.